# How can I unlock all the stars on my Trainer Card?

Tags: pokemon-heart-gold-soul-silver

How can I unlock those stars? What are the requirements?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

According to [Bulbapedia](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Trainer_stars#HeartGold_and_SoulSilver), you get a star on your **Trainer Card** for each of these achievements:

> - Get a record in the Hall of Fame
> - Complete the National Pokédex (excluding Mew, Celebi, Jirachi, Deoxys, Phione, Manaphy, Darkrai, Shaymin, and Arceus)
> - Beat records in all 10 Pokéathlon events
> - Show a Pokémon with five [Shiny Leaves](http://bulbapedia.bulbagarden.net/wiki/Shiny_Leaf) to Ethan/Lyra
> - Defeat 100 Trainers in a row in the Battle Tower

Comment: Thank you! 
To defeat 100 Trainers in a row, should it be in single mode? When i select double battle mode in order to tag with another Npc on the game, i only get to like 7 battles then i have to re-start again.

Comment: @Beavoru Yes, single mode.